# What does the error "ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" mean when I try to use TensorFlow?

Tags: cuda

I've seen other errors similar to this but always "libcudart.so.8.0" as opposed to " libcublas.so.8.0".

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package `libcublas8.0`. It's in the `multiverse` repository of Ubuntu 16.10 and later

Comment: Could you please elaborate?